# What am I? (round or flat)

Tags: riddle, poetry

What am I?

Some call me sphere
Some call me flat
I am a organism according to some intellectuals
Some say I am replaceable with others but for most I am the only one
People love me
I give the best but people use it against me
I am older than some but younger than many
I am more than what meets the eye
What people give me I will do, I do not do anything on my own

Note: after you find the answer in your explanation write how each line is related to the answer.

Edit:
In response to @goodguy5 comment.

> u got it correct. But a few mistakes. in the "I am a organism according to some intellectuals" I expected the [Gaia theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia_hypothesis) which was proposed by James Ephraim Lovelock a genius and agreed by other scientists. the 2nd mistake is "I am more than what meets the eye" I meant to say even if we are in space we cant see the whole Earth. We on earth see only a small part of earth now. And last but not least "People love me" I mean like companies and more people going green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Earth?

Some call me sphere

> The earth is round

Some call me flat

> Flat Earthers exist

I am a organism according to some intellectuals

> The concept that the earth itself is a living breathing organism is somewhat of a metaphor for how the earth changes

Some say I am replaceable with others but for most I am the only one

> Talks of terraforming Mars, or some other planet as a backup have been in science fiction for decades (if not longer), and some people view it as a viable future.

People love me

> I mean, here is da erf. round? anyway I love it

I give the best but people use it against me

> The earth has many resources, such as fossil fuels, and we harvest and utilize those resources, unfortunately producing A LOT of pollution in the process

I am older than some but younger than many

> The earth is neither the youngest nor oldest planet

I am more than what meets the eye

> This one is a little complicated, but I'm guessing that it's because there's the mantle and the core underneath the earth's surface? Not counting the depths of the ocean

What people give me I will do, I do not do anything on my own

> The earth is a canvas. Life grows on it, but without life, there is no atmosphere; it would just be a rock

Comment: Hello @VarunW. Your comment describes the answer directly. I tthink you should put that in Rot13 mode. That way readers who want to solve the riddle on their own can do so freely.

Comment: @DrD My bad I will add it to my question

Answer (score 0):

> An earthworm

Why

> Some call them roundworm, some call them flatworm

> We generally call them earthworm but we know they are organisms afterall.

> Some replace earthworm with fertilizers since earthworms are mostly used by farmers to convert dead materials into manure and utilizing it as nutrients for plants.

> Farmers love them

> Earthworms don't do any harm but many people see them as harmful insects and use pesticides.

> They are obviously younger and older than many

> People generally overlook the usage of earthworms in day to day life.

> Give earthworm dead and decomposing material and they'll do the work for you. Otherwise they would have no uae in the environment.

Comment: A [flatworm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatworm) is not a [earthworm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthworm). They are very different. Also a round worm is microscopic. They are not the same thing.

Comment: They can be confused if someone is not from the biology background. Flatworm, eathworm, roundworm, tapeworm are all different but many don't know the difference. You can argue on the same issue with the person above.